# Should I use the $inc operator with retryWrites enabled in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

Is it unwise to use the $inc operator (or similar additive operators) in MongoDB when retryWrites is enabled?

I've seen cases where some integer fields in my database appear to be inflated and I can't find the cause whatsoever -- it shouldn't be possible based on my code's logic. And it's very intermittent, approximately one instance per several writes of this type.

MongoDB seems to [warn that duplicate attempts can happen](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/retryable-writes/#failover-period), but is omitting certain operators under these conditions considered a best practice?